# Error: This recordset is not updateable

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2010, recordset

I'm stuck with this error for hours.
In the `open_form` event I set values to the `recordset` like this

`Id = vId`.
But with 1 form, no matter what field I update, I got this error.

```
This recordset is not updateable
```

I read this article http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?...kb;en-us;328828

I tried many things. Nothing work
There's no relation, I got the `navigation control`, the form is `dynaset`, I have a `primary key autoincrement`,
`allow edits` is enabled and `data entry` is set to yes

Also, I got the permission to edit this table

Anyone encountered this error before?

Also, I converted 97 to 2010 and now my tables are linked to `SQL server 2012`.
I don't know if it was working before cause it's not my app but I guess it was functional

Comment: Setting the form's Data Entry property to Yes means the form will not display existing records, only allow you to add new records.  Is that what you wanted?  However, I don't know whether that contributes to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: If the form's Record Source is a query, it may help to show us the query's SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now.You made me look at the Record source and there were 3 joins and one of them was on a table that the primary key wasn't set. I just set the Id to fix it. You can write it as an answer to get the points :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examine the form's Record Source.  If it's a `SELECT` statement, copy the SQL into SQL View of a new Access query.

Then open that query in Datasheet View.  If you can't edit the data in datasheet view, you will have to figure out how to revise the query so that it can return an editable record set.

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone, I had a different cause for this issue.

When we converted from one SQL Server to another, the people here deleted all of the linked tables and set them up again for each Access MDB.

For one table (which was actually pointing to a SQL View, and which was the linked table it was querying for the problem-causing form), the people didn't check off the column to specify the linked table's "index" (IIRC) columns... even though there was even a little comment in the dialog that it was necessary to check off a field(s) if you wanted to update.  Luckily, the view was selecting an ID, so I tried that and it worked.  (If that hadn't worked, I was going to specify the view column that formed the key of the SQL table that was the table being updated by the form.)

I had seen comments on forums about how "all of the update form's tables need to have an index", and I'd checked the SQL tables that the view was referencing, but it hadn't occurred to me that "table" meant the Access "linked table".  The only place I saw to specify the index on the linked table was when re-adding the linked table.